# How do I structure a repo with Cloud Run needing higher level code?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-run

I have added code to a repo to build a Cloud Run service. The structure is like this:
[image]

I want to run `b.py` in `cr`.

Is there any way I can deploy `cr` without just copying `b.py` into the `cr` directory? (I don't want to do it since here are lots of other folders and files that `b.py` represents).
The problem is due to the Dockerfile being unable to see folders above.
Also how would eg `api.py` import from `b.py`?

TIA you lovely people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your container with the correct parameters, and therefore, not to use the `gcloud run deploy --source=. ....` to build your container with default parameters

With docker, the `Dockerfile` by default is in the PATH/Dokerfile. But you can override that default behavior with the `-f` parameter to indicate the `Dockerfile` location.

For example, you can do that

```
cd top

docker build -f ./a/cr/Dockerfile .
```

Like that, you provide to the docker build runtime the current path (here `top`, and the current path is represented but the dot at the end `.`).

And you also specify the full path of the `Dockerfile` inside this current path.

So that, you have to update your `Dockerfile`, because the `COPY . .` will no longer copy the `cr` path, but the whole `top` directory.

---

**EDIT 1**

To validate my answer, I exactly do what you ask in your comment. I used `gcloud build summit` but:

- I ran the command from the `top` directory
- I created a `cloudbuild.yaml` file

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        docker build -f ./a/cr/Dockerfile -t <YOUR TAG> .
        docker push <YOUR TAG>
```

you can't perform a `gcloud builds submit --tag <YOUR TAG>` from the `top` directory if you haven't a `Dockerfile` in the root dir.

Comment: Thanks @guillaume blaquiere. That looks very useful but I was using gcloud builds submit to build the image in Artefact registry and then deploying it using that AR image. Can I still do that somehow?

Comment: I edited my answer according to your comment.