# Running python Flask app with maven-like folder structure on Google Cloud Run

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-run

How to configure Google Cloud Run to be able to run (via `gcloud run deploy`) a python Flask  app with the following source code structure?

```
root
│
├── src
│   └── app
│       └── main.py
│
├── Dockerfile
└── requirements.txt
```

Comment: Have a look at this [blog1](https://clincher.medium.com/deploy-a-simple-flask-application-in-google-cloud-run-bc0c644a31d5#:~:text=The%20folder%20structure%20looks%20as%20below%20after%20this%20particular%20step) & [blog2](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploy-a-python-flask-server-using-google-cloud-run-d47f728cc864#:~:text=Minimal%20structure%20%E2%80%94%20Basic,the%20following%20commands%3A) deploying a  flask application in Google Cloud Run

Comment: @SathiAiswarya, thanks for the links. Unfortunately the examples describes a flat project structure.

Comment: you should build a dockerfile specifying path to source,you can go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175306/how-do-i-structure-a-repo-with-cloud-run-needing-higher-level-code/75177874#75177874)

Answer (score 0):

Make it run based on [deploy-python-service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service) adding

```
RUN pip install .
```

after

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

and updating `CMD exec gunicorn` with the path `app.main` to `main`

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app.main:app
```

The overall `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install .

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app.main:app
```